# Django: run a Unix command from with Django?

Tags: django

Sorry if this is a duplicate - couldn't find an answer by searching.

How can I run a Unix command from within a Django views file? I want to run a 'cp' command to copy a file that's just been uploaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why command line `cp`?

Use [Python's builtin `copyfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) instead. Portable and much less error-prone.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
```

Comment: definitely true, use the python builtin.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the preferred way to run system program is to use the subprocess module, like:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.Popen('cp file1 file2',shell=True).wait()
```

Subprocess module is a replacement for os.system and other older modules and functions, see
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Of course if you need just to copy files you may use more convenient function [copyfile](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) from shutil module

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
import os
if os.system("cp file1 file2") == 0:
    # success
else:
    # failure
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Should have searched for Python!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [iterpipes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iterpipes), which reduces the 'By Hemidall's beard, what foul syntax!'  one tends to think when working with subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `subprocess.Popen()` for the general case.  It's more flexible than `os.system()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Popen/PIPE for that kind of stuff.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def script(script_text):
     p = Popen(args=script_text,
               shell=True,
               stdout=PIPE,
               stdin=PIPE)

     output, errors = p.communicate()
     return output, errors

script('./manage.py sqlclear my_database_name')
```

I would not recommend using **os.system** since it has got a number of limitations.

As [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) says:

> This is implemented by
>   calling the Standard C function
>   system(), and has the same
>   limitations. Changes to sys.stdin,
>   etc. are not reflected in the
>   environment of the executed command.